# How To automatically update resourse link in eclipse when files moved to other location

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I have imported website template in eclipse using file->import->General->Archive File..Template contains html files and also resource folder which contains CSS Javascript etc.I want to put html file in user folder and resource files in user_resource folder. But the problem i get is eclipse doesn't automatically update links in html file to the resource file.Do i manually  update all the links in HTML file or is there any way like dreamweaver  to update the links when file get moved to other location? For example i have link

```
<link href="user/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

it should automatically update to

```
<link href="../user_resource/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

when assets folder move to user_resource folder.

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used dreamweaver much. But I find these links may be useful to solve the problem if someone know how to use dreamweaver. 
Try it out...

http://www.whoi.edu/services/stad/classes/DreamWeaver/movingfilesfolders.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7c3ea.html